# How to save modules in a separate directory using a makefile

Tags: makefile, fortran

I am compiling some of my own FORTRAN code using a simple makefile but dislike having my code directory cluttered up with *.mod and *.o files.
Is there a simple way I can edit my makefile so that these compiled files are placed in a separate directory (something like ./obj/ )? I've searched through here and google to find a few examples but I can't get any of them working. Probably as I have very little experience of makefiles and fortran (have only coded C until now).

Below is my current makefile:

```
LIBBASE=/my/lib/dir/

HDF5LIB=$(LIBBASE)/hdf5/lib
HDF5INCLUDE=$(LIBBASE)/hdf5/include

MYLIB_LIB=$(LIBBASE)/mylib
MYLIB_INCLUDE=$(LIBBASE)/mylib

LIBS=-L$(HDF5LIB) -lhdf5 -lhdf5_fortran -lhdf5hl_fortran \
     -L$(MYLIB_LIB) -lmylib

INC=-I./ -I$(HDF5INCLUDE) -I$(MYLIB_INCLUDE) -DINCLUDE_MYLIB

# Compiler
F90     =   ifort
CC      =   ifort

FLAGS   =   -g -O2 -openmp

# ------ No machine-specific paths/variables after this  -----

FSOURCE = my_structures my_constants my_utils my_prog MainMOD
OBJECTS = my_structures.o my_constants.o my_utils.o my_prog.o

all:    $(FSOURCE)

MainMOD: MainMOD.F90 
    $(F90) $(FLAGS) -o  $@ $(INC) MainMOD.F90 $(LIBS) $(OBJECTS)
my_structures: my_structures.F90 
    $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $(INC) imager_structures.F90 $(LIBS) 
my_prog: my_prog.F90
    $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $(INC) my_prog.F90 $(LIBS) 
my_constants: my_constants.F90 
    $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $(INC) preproc_constants.F90 $(LIBS) 
utils: my_utils.F90 
    $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $(INC) my_utils.F90 $(LIBS) 

clean:
    rm -f $(FSOURCE) $(OBJECTS)

# Compilation rules


$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o: %.F90
    $(F90) $(FLAGS) -c $@ $<

# Rule to prevent make from identifying Fortran .mod files as Modula2 source
# files
%.o : %.mod
```

Comment: have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494915/how-to-write-a-makefile-to-generate-object-files-and-executable-in-different-dir

Comment: ifort has the `-module` option.

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488333/gfortran-how-to-control-output-directory-for-mod-files

Comment: The comment by @francescalus has helped: I've added the -module option and now the .mod files are stored separately. I used the -o option to place the .o files in the same subdir so now my question is partially solved. However, I noticed that my makefile is not paying attention to the rules: If I delete my file-specific compilation rules then the $(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o: %.F90 line does not help compile, I get a "no rule to make..." error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the way Makefile works is based on that *targets* and *sources* are in the same directory. For sure, you can do the opposite, but Makefile wasn't designed with that option in mind so you'll have to make your recipes a bit ugly.

Now, if I really wanted to have object files in a separate directory and wasn't bounded by using `make` only, I'd use `cmake` which in contrast to `make` assumes that sources are separated from the build files.

If you still want to go with `make`, then I think you need to fix one thing. 
From

```
$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o: %.F90
```

to

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.F90
```

Also,

> %.o : %.mod

is not required if you put

```
.SUFFIXES:
```

on the very first line of the file. This will turn off all [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) since you don't use them anyway.